# A variable declaration following an argument list

Tags: c, glibc

Reading [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html), I saw this piece of code in `string/strerror.c`:

```
char *
strerror (errnum)
     int errnum;
{
  char *ret = __strerror_r (errnum, NULL, 0);
  int saved_errno;

  if (__glibc_likely (ret != NULL))
    return ret;
  saved_errno = errno;
  if (buf == NULL)
    buf = malloc (1024);
  __set_errno (saved_errno);
  if (buf == NULL)
    return _("Unknown error");
  return __strerror_r (errnum, buf, 1024);
}
```

Note how there is a `int errnum` following the argument list.  How is this a valid syntax?  And what is it doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the old-style way of doing things, K&R, pre-ANSI.

Once function prototypes were introduced, this way of doing things was rendered obsolete.

Not *actually* obsolete since it's still valid even in C11 (as per `6.9.1 Function definitions /13`), but few people use it any more).

It's specifying the type of the parameter for the function block, similar to:

```
char *strerror (int errnum)
```

Comment: Under K&R all arguments were integers in the declaration `strerror (errnum)`, then type defined on the next line as I understand it.